# Discord.py Message object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I used channel.history() and trying now to print ID of the message or print the message, but I´m getting this error: TypeError: 'Message' object is not subscriptable. The problem is, when I´m not doing subscriptation, I get something like that:

<Message id=1044396942815412314 channel= type=<MessageType.default: 0> author= flags=>

How can I get the message or message ID from it to print it?

Thank you and sorry for my english.

This is code:

```
token = My token
import discord
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
listus = []
listus2 = []

kanal = 1044396925635534848

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(kanal)
    async for message in channel.history(limit=200):
        if message.author:
            print(message)


    
    
    
client.run(token)
```

Comment: "how can I get the message" you already have it, the "message" variable in that loop is a Message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `id` attribute of it (`message.id`)

Maybe I should tell you to read the documentation?
discord.py is one of the best documentated libraries in my opinion.
So I suggest you have a look on it: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html